# Variables ordered in mathematical analysis: why do we introduce the ordered variables?

Tags: calculus, proof-explanation, order-theory, book-recommendation

The theory of limits that I know at the time of university in Italy has been developed in a very general way by taking as a starting point the notion of an **ordered variable** from an ordered set of operations.

If $[O]$ is a strictly ordered set, I remember that an ordered variable $y$ definitely assumes a certain property if it is possible to determine an operation $O^{\ast}$ such that the indicated property can be verified by the results of all the operations $O$ following $O^{\ast}$ (i.e. $O\to O^{\ast}$).

In the case of convergence I wrote, if $\epsilon\in \Bbb R, \epsilon>0$ then:

> $$\ell\in\mathbb R\smallsetminus \{-\infty,+\infty \}$$
> and when $O\to O^{\ast}$
> $$|y-\ell|<\epsilon \iff \lim y=\ell$$

*Do any of you users know the theory of ordered variables, a well written book on this theme in Italian or English, that is also used for integrals, successions, limits and what is the practical meaning?*

Comment: Just my curiosity: what textbook used that approach to the theory of limits?

Comment: @Pacciu The book it is in Italian language: http://www.liguori.it/schedanew.asp?isbn=0445 the author is: Carlo Miranda (Napoli).

Comment: @Pacciu There is also this link for the odered variables:http://www.bdim.eu/item?fmt=pdf&id=BUMI_1954_3_9_2_202_0

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reference. ;-)

Comment: @Pacciu Ahahahh...my are olds remember. But why do we introduce the ordered variables?